# Not able to identify null values in dataset?

Tags: r, null

I have following data set:

```
Centre Ownership   CentreType   TG1     
2   1       2       
2   1       2       
2   1       2   2   
2   1       2   2   
2   1       2   2   
2   1       2   3   
1   1       2   2   
2   1       2       
1   1       2   2   
1   1       2   3   
1   1       2       
1   1       1
```

When I'm trying to find missing values by using code: `sapply(my_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`
There is 0 missing values shown. But in column TG1 there are multiple missing values. How to find them?

Comment: It will find only if the missing values are `NA` and that too not a string (`"NA"- is a string, `NA`  - real missing value)  Please check if you have `""` instead of `NA`   If it is blank, `sum(df == "")`

Comment: Try running this `is.na(NULL)`. `is.na` does not test for `NULL`.

Comment: @akrun it does give result. But suppose we have blank spaces in multiple columns and I want to get the sum of blank values in all the columns. Then what should I do?

Comment: Just do `colSums(df == "")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have NAs you have "".  You should probably convert them to NAs.  Here is how you count them

```
sapply(my_data, function(x) sum( trimws( x) %in% "" ))
```

Here is a way to convert them

```
mtcars[ 3, 3 ] <- ""
mtcars[ apply( mtcars , 2, function(X) trimws(X)=="")] <- NA
```